# Can a WebSocket handshake be sent on the same socket as an HTTP request?

Tags: websocket

Basically, is this interaction allowed by the standard? (Python pseudocode:)

```
import socket
s = socket.create_connection((host, 80))
s.send("GET /index.html HTTP/1.1\nHost:example.com\nConnection:keep-alive\n\n")
s.recv() // Should be a 200
s.send("GET /websocket HTTP/1.1\nHost:example.com\nUpgrade: websocket\nConnection: Upgrade\n\n")
s.recv() // Should be 101
```

Comment: Do you want to serialise your HTTP GET and WebSocket session or run them in parallel?  Do you want to write your client in python?

Comment: I am not looking for a library to simplify this, if that is what you're aiming at. I am asking if it can be serialized (if this is allowed or forbidden by the standard), or where in the standard is this specifically mentioned.

Comment: They can be serialised fine.  Your code snippet suggests you want to use the connections in parallel however.  If you removed the keepalive and read the full response to the first GET, you could reuse the socket for a websocket connection after.